# duplicate php packages

Tags: apt, server, package-management, 18.04, php

I use [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) repository for my php installation as its more up to date than Ubuntu's repository, but after I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 I can no longer install any php packages. for example, I need to install the curl extension but when I try to I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-curl : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so I uninstall php completely and now when I install php it installs the ubuntu version instead of the one I want.

Comment: Did you re-add that repository and did an update?

Comment: I removed the old entry of it and readded it and it worked, guess some of my 3rd party repos got messed up during the upgrade

Comment: @Eman Yes, the third party repos are disabled during the upgrade process, you need to reenable them *and* update them to use `bionic` instead of `xenial` as their target release.  The release upgrader does not do anything to the existing PPAs and third party repos except disable them during the upgrade process, and doesn't 'update' them to focus on the new release.

Comment: I realized that after hitting some roadblocks, I never had to re-enable repositories on a server before so I just removed them and readded them